# how to excute Query from

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

MySqlQuery:

```
    select count(holiday_id) 
    from holidays 
    where holiday_type_id=2 and DATEDIFF('2016-8-9',curdate())>=20
```

JavaQuery:

```
    Query OptionalholidaysQuery = 
          manager.createNativeQuery("select count(holiday_id) from Parabola.holidays"
                 + " where holiday_type_id=2 and DATEDIFF(:startdate,curdate())>=20");

    OptionalholidaysQuery.setParameter("startdate", "2016-8-9");
    List<Integer> optionalholidays = (List<Integer>) OptionalholidaysQuery.getResultList();
    System.out.println("Optional:" + OptionalholidaysQuery);
```

The given MySql query is working fine and returns data when I execute it via workbench.

I have applied it in Java code but it is giving me as result

> Optional:org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl@220ab636

Please point out the mistake and suggest corrections.

Comment: What did you expect it to print? You've told it to print the `Query` object so that's exactly what it printed. If you want to print the *results* you'll have to print the `optionalholidays` object instead. It would also be much easier if you formatted your code properly. Right now it's not the easiest thing to read.

Comment: No Exception am getting org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl@220ab636
 this i am getting in return

Comment: No, that's just what the `toString` of the object returned by `createNativeQuery(String)` returns, and is what your `println` statement has been told to print out. The *results* are contained in `optionalholidays`, *which you aren't printing out at all*.

Comment: so what  we have to change we take it as String Parameter?

Comment: `createNativeQuery` is fine. It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. Your problem is your `System.out.println` statement, you're printing the wrong object.

Comment: yes please wait let me check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117675/discussion-between-research-development-and-jonk).

Comment: Please point out what problem you're having and then people can maybe suggest corrections ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are printing your queryHolder instead of printing the results.Change your code like below

Your Version

```
List<Integer> optionalholidays = (List<Integer>) OptionalholidaysQuery.getResultList();
System.out.println("Optional:"+OptionalholidaysQuery);
```

update like this.

```
List<Integer> optionalholidays = (List<Integer>) OptionalholidaysQuery.getResultList();
for(final Integer optionalHoldiday : optionalHolidays){
    System.out.println("Optional:"+optionalholiday );
}
```

This will print your optional holiday one after the other. Please let me know if you have any doubts with this.